# How to determine the absolute top and left position according to an angle? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angle, box

So i have a box that is in absolute position. Now my goal is to take an angle as the input from the user and move that box in that angle.
My logic was to take the angle and convert that into top and left positioning so that it moves accordingly. But the speed varies as due to the pixel difference.
Any suggestions in another method or help in this one?
Also, i am taking velocity and angle as the input from the user.

Thank you.

```
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #FCF4D9;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're best off using the css "transform" property, which allows you to rotate or translate (aka move) an element.

The syntax for this is

```
.box {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}
```

But for compatibility you should also always add

```
-moz-transform: rotate(50deg);
```

The transform attribute moves your element as indicated without affecting any other elements around it.  The transformation will take effect from wherever the element is already positioned by the "top" and "left" attributes.

You can also use this property to translate, or move, the element

```
transform: translate( 50px, 50px);
```

will move the element 50 pixels to the right and 50 pixels down.  These properties can be used in conjunction:

```
transform: translate( 50px, 50px) rotate(50deg);
```

will move the element and then rotate it, while

```
transform: rotate(50deg) translate(50px, 50px);
```

will first rotate the element, then move it 50 pixels to the right and down, relative to the rotation already applied.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/dtgt6s2u/) helps you.

```
var applyButton = document.getElementById("apply");
applyButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
  var angle = parseFloat(document.getElementById('angle').value.trim() || "0");
  var box = document.getElementById("rotate-box");
  box.style['transform'] = "rotate("+angle+"deg)";
});
```